# Multithreading Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am using visual studio and the following threading examples generate errors,

```
std::thread thread_1(addToCatalogVariablee(stage_completion, m_load_profiles, m_load_stable_instances, m_load_instance_round, m_load_instance_struct));

std::thread thread_2(printReport(m_load_stable_instances, m_file_name_in));
```

printReport and addToCatalogVariablee have both defined in a seperate header and class file. However visual studio flags both lines as,

Error:no instance of constructor matches the argument list
   argument types are:(void)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It would be good if you read manual: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a wild guess:  You want to call `printReport` in a separate thread, passing as arguments the two member variables.  That's not what you are doing with the sample code.  You are calling the function *in this thread*, and then passing the result of that function to the constructor of `std::thread`.

If `printReport` is an ordinary function, or a static member function, then what you need is just:

```
std::thread thread_2(printReport, m_load_stable_instances, m_file_name_in);
```

If `printReport` is a non-static member function of this class, then you will need:

```
std::thread thread_2(&ThisClass::PrintReport, this, 
                        m_load_stable_instances, m_file_name_in);
```